# Why didn't MACUSA obliviate Jacob at first meeting?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

If MACUSA know Jacob is No-Maj, then why can't they
obliviate him immediately?

Why didn't MACUSA obliviate Jacob at the first meeting?

Comment: The trailer for the new Fantastic Beasts movie shows Jacob in the Great Hall at Hogwarts which suggests the possibility that he might be a Squib

Comment: I don't really understand the question as the command to obliviate Jacob is given immediately and only is not done because Queeny sais she will do this and then runs away with Jacob...

Comment: @SpacePhoenix -- Or something else...

Comment: To quote Ryan George, "So that the movie can happen."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can, and as far as they were aware they did.

The problem is the person they assigned to do it decided not to.